# New conenttype: inline fields

Tags: drupal, field, backend, contenttypes

With my Drupal 7 installation for cars I want to add 2 fields:

> xxx Nm @ xxx RPM

I created two fields within my contenttype:

1. field for Nm
2. field for RPM

In the admin, when adding a new car, I want to place these two fields next to eachother. Currently, it's showing this way:

```
Nm: [input]
RPM: [input]
```

I want to show it on the following way (because they are related to eachother):

```
[input] Nm @ [input] RPM
```

Is there a (standard) way to do this, do I need to install a module? I can't find it...

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Here are your options :

1) Use css to move it. If you share your page I can give you a more specific way to do this.
You will need to modify the style.css file . The good thing about is that you can do this fast the bad thing is if you want to modify things further you should do the second option.

2) Make a theme in drupal and use node content type to make your own layout.

Further reading

https://drupal.org/node/17565

Comment: pls make the answer as complete